# How To Remove Redundent ?p=1 From URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I had an issue where my pagination would append a ?p=1 to the end of a URL when moving from page 2 back to page 1. With the issue corrected so those links no longer get served, I do have to try and find a way to do a 301 redirect from those URLs to the proper URL so that the search engines can update those links.

I am on an Apache server, and I would like to be able to use RedirectMatch 301 to do this, however I do not think that it plays well with query strings.

```
RedirectMatch 301 (.*)?p=1 http://mydomain.com/$1
```

does not do the trick

I believe the solution is going to end up being that I use RedirectCond and Rewrite statements to make this work, however I do not know how to get this to redirect.

Can someone help me out with this? What I have so far gives me Internal Server Errors so obviously I am not on the right track yet.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^?p=1$
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://devserver/$1 [L,R=301]
```

If someone can even point me toward a good tutorial on how to set this up would be helpful too.

Comment: Some additional looking showed that I may not even need the first RewriteCond since I want to redirect anything with a ?p=1 inside of it.

Comment: I've also found that my second line should be RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=1$ . It now looks like I just need to get the RewriteRule to direct to the correct spot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)p=1(&|$)
RewriteRule . http://devserver%{REQUEST_URI}? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I think you are close. The URL I am requesting is: http://devserver/footwear/mens-work-boots/6-inch-work-boots.html and when I put in this redirect, it takes me to http://devserver/index.php

Comment: @Josh Pennington I don't see `?p=1` in your URL. Does the redirect happen? Maybe another `RewriteRule` overrides it. Can you show complete config of rewrites?

Comment: Sorry. I copied the URL wrong. There should have been a ?p=1 at the end of it.

Comment: It still redirected to index.php (I do appreciate your help)

Comment: Josh Pennington: I can't figure out what's wrong. Try to set `RewriteLog` with `RewriteLogLevel 2` and show log.

Comment: I moved your code higher up in my htaccess file and it started working. thanks!